# Number of power residues modulo prime power

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences

Suppose you have a prime $p$ (not necessarily odd) and you have $\tau$ defined by $p^\tau \| k$ for some integer $k$. Then you define
\begin{equation}
y = \begin{cases}
\tau + 1 &, p > 2 \textrm{ or } p = 2 \textrm{ & }\tau = 0\\
\tau + 2 &, p = 2 \textrm{ & } \tau > 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then we can use chapter 6, section 5 of Vinogradov's Elements of Number Theory to say that there are, at least for odd primes, $\phi(p^{\tau + 1})/(k, \phi(p^{\tau + 1}))$ $k$th power residues, modulo $p^y$.

1) What does the condition $p^\tau \| k$ give us? I could understand if we were just stripping multiples of $p$ off $k$ so that we could essentially work with $1 \leq k \leq p$ but this doesn't seem to be for that.

2) I'm guessing that the reason for question (1) tells us why we want $y$ to have that form, and I've got a rough feeling as to why we have that form for odd primes, but I'm really not seeing it for $p = 2$

3) The book goes on to say that the number of solutions to $x^k \equiv a \pmod{p^y}$ is $p^{y - \tau - 1}(k, \phi(p^{\tau + 1}))$ which, again, I see in the case for odd primes but for $p = 2$ I'm missing something (and most texts I've got access to seem to ignore power residues modulo $2^\alpha$.

4) It also then goes on to state without proof that if $a$ is a $k$th power residue modulo $p^y$ then it is a $k$th power residue modulo $p^t$ for all $t$, which I guess is also connected to some fundamental property about the definition of $y$ which I'm just being really stupid about.

Any help with these four questions would be appreciated :)

Comment: The group of units modulo $p^y$ is cyclic when $p > 2$ or when $p = 2 \wedge y \leq 2$. [But for $p = 2$ and $y > 2$ it is a direct product of $\mathbb Z/2$ by $\mathbb Z/2^{y-2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Powers_of_2). That's why the extra care for that case. The $k$-th power residues modulo $p^y$ (and I am fairly sure that the author means only the $k$-th power residues that are invertible modulo $p^y$) are simply the multiples of $k$ in the group of units; so the whole question boils down to basic properties of cyclic groups.